# List of fields that did not pass model validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I'm working on ASP.NET WebAPI, that serve json array of clients, and gets array of mofications.

```
[ValidateModel]
public IHttpActionResult POSTClient(Client[] clients)
{
    foreach (Client c in clients)
    {
         ClientBLL.ModyfiClient(c);
    }
    return Ok();
}    


public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            var errorsList = new List<string>();
            foreach(var modelError in actionContext.ModelState)
            {
                errorsList.Add(modelError.Key);
            }
            var response = new
            {
                errorThrow = "invalid model",
                errors = errorsList,
                sender = "api",
                status = "customerror"
            };

            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, response, actionContext.ControllerContext.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
        }
    }
}
```

And I am getting

```
{
    "errorThrow": "invalid model",
    "errors": [
        "clients[0]",
        "clients[1]"
    ],
    "sender": "api",
    "status": "customerror"
}
```

But I want to return ValidateModel errors in specific way with number of array entry and name of field that did not pass validation. How to get name of field from actionContext.ModelState?

Comment: `var errors = ModelState.Keys.Where(k => ModelState[k].Errors.Count > 0).Select(k => new { propertyName = k, errorMessage = ModelState[k].Errors[0].ErrorMessage });` will give you a list of the property names and the associated error

Comment: Result is:
`{
    "errorThrow": "invalid model",
    "errors": [
        {
            "propertyName": "clients[0]",
            "errorMessage": ""
        }
    ],
    "sender": "api",
    "status": "customerror"
}`
No information about specific field in model that did not pass validation.

Comment: Execute that code in the method itself and see what the result is.

Comment: I executed this in POSTClient and in OnActionExecuting. Results are prete much same `[0] { propertyName = "clients[0]", errorMessage = "" } <Anonymous Type>`.

Comment: Then what is you `Client` model and what validation attributes have you applied to its properties? (the result you getting does not make sense)

Comment: OK. You're right. ClientID was not nullable.
`[Required]
public int ClientID { get; set; }`
When I changed it to int? I've got 
`{ propertyName = "clients[0].ClientID", errorMessage = "Filed ClientID` jest is required." }
But, is there any resonable way to get raw field name, without striping string?

Comment: What do you mean _get raw field name, without striping string_?

Comment: Name of field, without additional informations.

Comment: Just remove the `errorMessage = ModelState[k].Errors[0].ErrorMessage` bit in the above query - but what would be the point of just returning the property name without the error message?

Comment: Well I don't know is my english is so poor, or something but I want to return list of fields so on the AngularJS frontend app, or KendoUI grid, I'll mark specific fields as containing wrong data.

Comment: So what is it that your actually want to return? In order to match up the errors with you fields, then you would need all that information